# Monitoring directory for changes from web service

Tags: java, spring-ws

Don't know if it is clear from title, I'll explain it deeper.

First of all limitations: Java 1.5 IBM.

This is the situation:

I have spring web service that receives request with pdf document in it. I need to put this pdf into the some **input** directory that AFP application (not of the importance) monitors. This AFP application takes that pdf, do something with it and returns it to some **output** directory that I need to monitor. Monitoring of output directory would take some time, probably 30 seconds. Also, I know what is exact file name that I expect to appear in output directory. If nothing appears in 30 seconds than I would return some fault response.

Because of my poor knowledge of web services and multithreading I don't know in which possible problems I can fall into.
Also, searching the internet I realize that most of people recommend watchservice for directory monitoring, but this is introduced in Java 7.
Any suggestion, link, idea would be helpful.

Comment: Do you know the exact file name _only_ or the _full path_ to the generated file?

Comment: I know exact directory location, exact file name, so full path.

Comment: OK, and about these 30 seconds? Are they the timeout of a request to your service?

Comment: No, I just don't wont to wait longer than 30 seconds.

Comment: So, you submit the original PDF to the other app, then poll the directory for 30 seconds max in a single method?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to achieve.

Comment: OK, I have made some sample code, but without knowing the full context, it is rather hard to make it relevant ;)

Answer (score 1):

So, the scenario is simple. In a main method, the following actions are done in order:

- call the AFP service;
- poll the directory for the output file;
- deal with the output file.

We suppose here that `outputFile` is a `File` containing the absolute path to the generated file; this method returns `void`, adapt:

```
// We poll every second, so...

private static final int SAMPLES = 30;

public void dealWithAFP(whatever, arguments, are, there)
    throws WhateverIsNecessary
{
    callAfpService(here);

    int i = 0;
    try {
        while (i < SAMPLES) {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            if (outputFile.exists())
                break;
        }
        throw new WhateverIsNecessary();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Throw it back if the method does, otherwise the minimum is to:
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new WhateverIsNecessary();
    }

    dealWithOutputFile(outputFile);
}
```